# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing defs

Tags: python, h5py

I'm trying to install `sentence-transformers` library. But when I import it, this error pops out:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-c9f0b8c65221> in <module>
----> 1 import h5py

~\Anaconda3\envs\custom_env\lib\site-packages\h5py\__init__.py in <module>
     32         raise
     33 
---> 34 from . import version
     35 
     36 if version.hdf5_version_tuple != version.hdf5_built_version_tuple:

~\Anaconda3\envs\custom_env\lib\site-packages\h5py\version.py in <module>
     15 
     16 from collections import namedtuple
---> 17 from . import h5 as _h5
     18 import sys
     19 import numpy

h5py\h5.pyx in init h5py.h5()

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing defs: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I have installed `h5py` library. What am I missing?

Comment: There's a bug somewhere, which is all that can be said from the info you provide. Generally, try to create a [mcve] and provide verifiable/observable info. Also read [ask] and check for bug reports in the upstream bugtracking system.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt thank you for your answer. I cannot provide code, since the error just pops in `import h5py`

Comment: I cannot reproduce this prob. Are you running the code on a venv btw? Edit: stupid question. Yes, you are. The issue might start there. I got a similar situation for another package where the DLLs existed only in the `base` env and although the package was installed in `my_venv`, the respective DLLs were not. I copied them from `base` into an equivalent folder in `my_venv`. (I did not get this issue for `h5py` btw)

Comment: @noober Like `Ulrich Eckhardt` mentioned, you should update your question. Refer your env structure and include the minimal working example (which is not much work). Refer system and environment (for instance, you're using anaconda, versions?, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem after a CUDA/CUdnn update that probably messed some DLLs.
I did: `pip uninstall h5py`, which indicated a successful uninstall along with some error messages. And immediately after `pip install h5py`

Sometimes simple solutions work.

Comment: Same here, same cause for the problem, though I had initially installed it via conda. Reinstalling via pip solved it.